# How do I fix TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when column in df has nan?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, precision

I have a dataframe

```
dfooc
Name AddressId
XYZ  nan
ABC  <memory at 0x7f145136ca10>
HIJ  nan
```

How do I convert this AddressId column to float type?
it is currently -

```
Name: AddressId, Length: 346498, dtype: object
```

I tried

```
dfooc['AddressId'] = int(float(dfooc['AddressId']))
raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I am converting this to float because if i let this be as it is, im unable to get this columns data into SQL server and im guessing its because SQL server doesnt like '<memory at 0x7f145136ca10>'

Comment: use: `dfooc['AddressId'] = dfooc['AddressId'].astype(float)`

Comment: @Clegane this gives ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<memory at 0x7f145136ca10>'

Comment: okey, use: `dfooc['AddressId'] = dfooc['AddressId'].astype(float,errors='ignore')`

Comment: Thanks @Clegane this worked. I have a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158199/why-do-i-receive-programming-error-supplied-value-is-not-a-valid-instance-of-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
dfooc['AddressId'] = dfooc['AddressId'].astype('float', errors = 'ignore')
```

`errors` control raising of exceptions on invalid data for provided dtype according to the documentation, set to `ignore`, it will ssuppress exceptions and on error return original object (i.e. nan).

Or you can fillna first and then convert the series to float :

```
dfooc['AddressId'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
dfooc['AddressId'] = dfooc['AddressId'].astype('float')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot impute the data without compromising final output. but fooc['AddressId'] = dfooc['AddressId'].astype('float', errors = 'ignore') works. I have a similar issue but with date column at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158199/why-do-i-receive-programming-error-supplied-value-is-not-a-valid-instance-of-a